# Group multiple rasters in MapServer?

Tags: qgis, raster, mapserver, mapfile, india

I had a map file for each state (raster file) of India. Now I want to group all map files to show  a single raster or single map file?

How I can do in using QGIS or any platform?.

Comment: I would start by reading about the use of tileindex http://www.mapserver.org/optimization/tileindex.html

Comment: You could do this without setting up any tile index by simply grouping the layers within MapServer, see: http://mapserver.org/mapfile/layer.html#layer

Answer (score 3):

In [MapServer](https://mapserver.org/) you can group layers together using the `GROUP` directive in the `LAYER` part of your map file.

So for an India service, you might have

```
MAP
    NAME "India"

    LAYER
        NAME "Andhra_Pradesh"
    END

    LAYER
        NAME "Arunachal_Pradesh"
    END

    LAYER
        NAME "Assam"
    END

    LAYER
        NAME "Bihar"
    END
    # etc...

END
```

with individual layers for each state pointing pointing at data for each state (raster or vector or some combination...)

And group them together like:

```
MAP
    NAME "India"

    LAYER
        GROUP "all_states"
        NAME "Andhra_Pradesh"
    END

    LAYER
        GROUP "all_states"
        NAME "Arunachal_Pradesh"
    END

    LAYER
        GROUP "all_states"
        NAME "Assam"
    END

    LAYER
        GROUP "all_states"
        NAME "Bihar"
    END
    # etc...

END
```

And if you have a WMS, then in the metadata of **one** of the layers then you add some group metadata like:

```
MAP
    NAME "India"

    LAYER
        GROUP "all_states"
        NAME "Andhra_Pradesh"
        METADATA
            "WMS_GROUP_TITLE" "States of India"
            "WMS_GROUP_ABSTRACT" "Grouped layer of the states and provinces of India
        END
    END

    LAYER
        GROUP "all_states"
        NAME "Arunachal_Pradesh"
    END

    LAYER
        GROUP "all_states"
        NAME "Assam"
    END

    LAYER
        GROUP "all_states"
        NAME "Bihar"
    END
    # etc...

END
```

Comment: Also Mapserver will only consider the group metadata of the first layer, but it doesn't consider an error if more than one has them (the rest will just be ignored).